# Redshift create Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "identity"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am new at redshift. I am trying to create table which having auto increment id.
I used syntax from documentation, yet its throwing an error

> Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "identity"

My sql statement is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
id BIGINT identity(0, 1) NOT NULL,
orderid BIGINT )
```

Comment: From *which* documentation? I think you're reading docs for the wrong database. In PostgreSQL and drivatives that's usually `id serial primary key`

Comment: from amazon-redshift documentation 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_examples.html

Comment: OK, another deviation from PostgreSQL then. Untagging PostgreSQL, this is clearly redshift specific, and until they offer free public access there's not much point asking PostgreSQL users about stuff that requires redshift access. What's this got to do with [tag:mysql] btw?

Comment: Your sql works through psql client on my redshift cluster. Your client tool may cause it.

Comment: @MasashiMiyazaki exactly this happens!

Answer (score 0):

This query runs perfectly fine with PSQL client to Redshift. There may be client issue using that you're connecting to Redshift. Try using some other client or programming language like Java, Ruby, Python etc.